# Pass json file into JAR or read from spark session

Tags: scala, apache-spark, jar

I have a Spark UDF written on Scala. I'd like to use my function with some additional files.

```
import scala.io.Source
import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods.parse
import org.json4s.DefaultFormats

object consts {
    implicit val formats = DefaultFormats
    val my_map = parse(Source.fromFile("src/main/resources/map.json").mkString).extract[Map[String, Map[String, List[String]]]]
}
```

Now I want to use `my_map` object inside UDF. So I basically do this:

```
import package.consts.my_map

object myUDFs{
 *bla-bla and use my_map*
}
```

I've already tested my function in a local, so it works well.
Now I want to understand how to pack a jar file so that `.json` file stays there?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you manage your project with *[Maven](https://maven.apache.org/)*, you can place your `.json` file(s) under `src/main/resources` as it's the default place where *Maven* looks for your project's resources.

You also can define a custom path for your resources as described here: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/resource-directory.html

Answer (score 0):

UPD: I managed to do so by creating fatJar and reading my resource file this way:

```
    Source
      .fromInputStream(
        getClass.getClassLoader.getResourceAsStream("map.json")
      )
      .mkString
  ).extract[Map[String, Map[String, List[String]]]]
```